# How to return content of a nested indexed field with some top level fields using Mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

Consider these documents:

```
{
  "chapterNumber": "1",
  "contents": [
    {
      "paragraphNumber": "1 ",
      "paragraphCleanText": "cleaned content 1",
      "contents": [
        "not clean content",
        {
          "p": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "paragraphNumber": "1 ",
      "paragraphCleanText": "cleaned content 2",
      "contents": [
        "not clean content",
        {
          "p": null
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
{
  "chapterNumber": "2",
  "contents": [
    {
      "paragraphNumber": "1 ",
      "paragraphCleanText": "cleaned content 3",
      "contents": [
        "not clean content",
        {
          "p": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "paragraphNumber": "1 ",
      "paragraphCleanText": "cleaned content 4",
      "contents": [
        "not clean content",
        {
          "p": null
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

If I do an index on the field `paragraphCleanText` and then issue a query to search for this string `cleaned content 3`, is there a way to return the following structure from a single or optimized query?

```
{
  "chapterNumber": "2",
  "paragraphNumber": "1 ",
  "paragraphCleanText": "cleaned content 3"
}
```

Comment: Is value of `paragraphCleanText` unique in contents array of each doc ?

Comment: You have to use array projections. See [projection operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#projection-operators). There are some example sin the provided link. I an, addition Aggregation query is another way to get the result.

Comment: @SaidAkh : Is it working or still having issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a pretty simple solution for my use case:

1. add an index on `paragraphCleanText` field, plus `chapterNumber` and `paragraphNumber` as additional fields
2. make the following query `db.yourCollection.find({"contents.paragraphCleanText" : { $regex: /^ some text that is present in the field .*/ } })._addSpecial( "$returnKey", true )`
   `

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) for this :

1.If your `"contents.paragraphCleanText"` is unique :

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Filter docs based on condition */
    { $match: { "contents.paragraphCleanText": "cleaned content 3" } },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        chapterNumber: 1,
        /** contents will be an object, which is matched object, as `$filter` will return an array of matched objects, we're picking first object - assuming `contents.paragraphCleanText` is unique,
          *  Just in case if you've multiple objects that matches with given condition use `$reduce` instead of `$filter + $arrayElemAt` */
        contents: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            { $filter: { input: "$contents", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.paragraphCleanText", "cleaned content 3" ] } } },
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        chapterNumber: 1,
        paragraphNumber: "$contents.paragraphNumber",
        paragraphCleanText: "$contents.paragraphCleanText"
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uNUjPDJycA0)

**Note :** If you want entire object from `contents` array that matches condition then you can simply use [$elemmatch-projection-operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#elemmatch-projection) or [$-positional-projection-operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_), but as you don't want the entire object and just couple of fields from the matched object then you need to use  aggregation cause `projection` option in `.find()` is not capable of transforming fields - it's only capable of including or excluding fields from document, So you'll use `$project` stage of aggregation to do this.

2. If your `"contents.paragraphCleanText"` can have duplicates i.e; there can be multiple objects inside `contents` array with `"contents.paragraphCleanText": "cleaned content 3"` :

**Query :**

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { "contents.paragraphCleanText": "cleaned content 3" } },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        chapterNumber: 1,
        contents: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$contents",
            initialValue: [], // create an empty array to start with 
            in: {
              $cond: [
                {
                  $eq: [ "$$this.paragraphCleanText", "cleaned content 3" ] // Condition to check
                },
                { // If an object has matched with condition concatinate array converted that object into holding array
                  $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ { paragraphCleanText: "$$this.paragraphCleanText", paragraphNumber: "$$this.paragraphNumber" } ] ]
                },
                "$$value" // If current object is not matched return holding array as is 
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {$unwind : '$contents'} // Purely optional stage - add this stage & test output to decide whether to include or not & add `$project` stage after this stage
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8ma4A5siRr5)

Comment: Thanks, @whoami for the response. I found a solution